# How to redirect page before refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, redirect

Suppose I have 2 web pages, I want the entrance of Page2 to be Page1.
Therefore, when user try to reload/refresh Page2, he will be redirected to Page1 first then redirect to Page2.
Below is the code I used in Page1 which redirect to Page2:

```
$(window).load(function () {            
    location.href = "Page2.aspx";
});
```

How can I make user refresh of Page2 redirect to Page1?

Comment: And you believe browser will allow doing you so??

Comment: if you want to run the logic of page 1 before page 2 loads every time.you need to put that logic in page 2.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.onunload = unloadPage;
function unloadPage()
{
    window.location.href = "page2.html";
}
```

not sure it works didn test it

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the keyboard's <kbd>F5</kbd> keypress like this:

```
$(window).on(
    'keydown',
    function(e){
        if(e.which == 116){       // F5 == key 116
            location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            e.preventDefault();   // For good measure
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

Other than that, you can't **reliably** redirect on unload.